# Is VPN inside VirtualBox guest applied only to guest OS traffic?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, virtualbox

Recently one of my clients purchased routers and firewall service from WatchGuard. They asked everyone useing their network to install a private certificate, so that they can seamlessly unpack all SSL traffic, analyze it and then re-pack and sign it.

I'd like to keep my traffic private, so I did not install the certificate and I'm not useing client's internet connection anymore.

However, I have to use clients VPN to access some services and push my work. The admin admitted that soon they will also install use the same firewall for VPN traffic and the configuration will be "when connected to VPN, all traffic will go through VPN".

I'd like to avoid that, as I don't want my private gmail (and other private services) traffic to be routed through this "man in the middle" VPN of my client.

For my working environment I use VirtualBox (to seperate each clients environment and also this way I can easily backup the entire environement, before installing/trying something new that could potentially break it).

If I connect to VPN on the Guest OS (inside VirtualBox), regardless of VPN's configuration, only the Guest OS traffic should be routed via VPN, is that right?

I mean, the guest OS is not aware of the host OS and so the VPN inside the guest OS should also not be aware it's running in virtualized context?

So my private gmail run from my Host OS browser traffic should not be routed through clients VPN, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The hosts's routing table is not affected by that which resides in the guest.